# GoDaddy + Microsoft 365: Send email using SMTP works on locally but fails on hosted website (C# ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, smtp, microsoft365

**Hosting**: GoDaddy Windows Hosting
**Platform**: ASP.NET MVC C# .NET Framework 4.8
**Email**: Microsoft 365
**SMTP Settings**:
Host: smtp.office365.com
Port: 587
DeliveryMethod: Network
EnableSsl: true
Credentials: Username & Password

Send email works fine when run the web application on local (IIS Express), but smtp.send() throws below error when deployed on hosting server.

---

```
{
  "ClassName": "System.Net.Mail.SmtpException",
  "Message": "**Failure sending mail.**",
  "Data": null,
  "InnerException": {
    "ClassName": "System.Net.WebException",
    "Message": "Unable to connect to the remote server",
    "Data": null,
    "InnerException": {
      "NativeErrorCode": 10013,
      "ClassName": "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
      "Message": "**An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions**",
      "Data": null,
      "InnerException": null,
      "HelpURL": null,
      "StackTraceString": " at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)\\r\\n at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)",
      "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
      "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
      "ExceptionMethod": "8\\nDoConnect\\nSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\\nSystem.Net.Sockets.Socket\\nVoid DoConnect(System.Net.EndPoint, System.Net.SocketAddress)",
      "HResult": -2147467259,
      "Source": "System",
      "WatsonBuckets": null
    },
    "HelpURL": null,
    "StackTraceString": " at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)\\r\\n at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)\\r\\n at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)\\r\\n at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)\\r\\n at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)\\r\\n at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)\\r\\n at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()\\r\\n at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)",
    "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
    "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
    "ExceptionMethod": "8\\nGetConnection\\nSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\\nSystem.Net.ServicePoint\\nSystem.Net.Sockets.Socket GetConnection(System.Net.PooledStream, System.Object, Boolean, System.Net.IPAddress ByRef, System.Net.Sockets.Socket ByRef, System.Net.Sockets.Socket ByRef)",
    "HResult": -2146233079,
    "Source": "System",
    "WatsonBuckets": null
  },
  "HelpURL": null,
  "StackTraceString": " at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)\\r\\n at Inol.BAL.EmailMgmt.SendTestEmail() in C:\\code\\inol\\Inol\\BAL\\EmailMgmt.cs:line 283\\r\\n at Inol.Controllers.TestEmailController.Index(TestEmailModel model) in C:\\code\\inol\\Inol\\Controllers\\TestEmailController.cs:line 30",
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": "8\\nSend\\nSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\\nSystem.Net.Mail.SmtpClient\\nVoid Send(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage)",
  "HResult": -2146233088,
  "Source": "System",
  "WatsonBuckets": null,
  "Status": -1
}
```

Already tried changing port to 25, but result is same!

What am I missing to rid of forbidden access?

Answer (score 0):

So, `SMTP` is an old service. When you use port `587` you are using EXPLICIT TLS, NOT IMPLICIT TLS.

As far as I have found, only **Gmail** & **Rackspace** support connections on port `485` so in your case is definetly port `587`.

This is because the client first connects on port `587`, then **after** username & password are successful, **it upgrades the connection to TLS**.

This is not the same as IMPLICT TLS which connects encrypted from the start on port `485`.

If you are using port `587`, I imagine you would `EnableSsl: false` which is **a setting the often forces port** `485`.

Comment: I have set the **EnabledSsl: true** with **Port 587**.